# Android to Arduino - Can't upload a sketch

Tags: android-pendingintent, samsung-mobile, arduino-ide, led

I tried uploading a sketch onto my Arduino Nano board from my Samsung S10 device and I always stumble upon this error.

Here is the error:

name.antonsmirnov.arduinostudio: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

I'm a noob.

I tried looking up my problem online and found some solution but when I try those said solution, they never work for my project. All I want is for my LED Strip to be 100% portable and I need to be able to upload sketch via my smartphone. My code works fine when I connect the LED Strip to my Windows 10 Desktop Computer, but when I try by using the ArduinoStudio app. it never works.

Here is the complete code;

```
#include <FastLED.h> 
#define LED_PIN 2 
#define NUM_LEDS 332 

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS]; 

void setup() { 
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
FastLED.setMaxPowerInVoltsAndMilliamps(5, 500); 
FastLED.clear(); 
FastLED.show(); 


void loop() { 
leds[0] = CRGB(100, 0, 0); 
leds[10] = CRGB(40, 40, 40); 
leds[143] = CRGB(100, 0, 0); 
leds[214] = CRGB(100, 0, 0); 
FastLED.show(); 
}
```

As I said, I'm a noob and it would probably make my whole life better if somebody can just copy my code, write down what I need to write and where I need to write it.
If he/she can also explain how and why, it would be better, but unnecessary.

Thanks to my futur hero !

Answer (score 0):

i have the solution, download the apk file of arduinodroid, its an app made for old version of android and isnt available in play store, it works perfectly for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).